# Should question text restate the title?

Tags: discussion, questions

I don't like getting emails where the first sentence is in the subject line, and the second sentence is in the body of the email.  I also dislike forum posts which do the same.  For example, [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/713/93) starts with the words "For example," which to me is confusing. It seems like I just stepped into the middle of a conversation.

Are there any guidelines on this?  Is it okay for the body of the post to be a continuation of the text in the title?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's better if the question body is self-contained. Generally, the question title should summarize the problem, and the question body should go into more detail, so there won't be any repeated text. It may occasionally happen that the title is a good first sentence for the question; if so, the body should start with that sentence.

Readers read the title and the body independently. Editors may edit the one without editing the other. You can't assume that the body will always be read immediately after the current title.

On a related note, don't assume that readers have read the tags before they read the question body, either.

[Similar question on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173271/questions-in-titles-need-to-be-repeated-why)